# Adding a string List to a dictionary, then retrieving it's values

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I am creating test scenarios using Selenium, Specflow, C#. I have a List and added it to a scenarioContext dictionary. Now I want to retrieve it in a different step definition. How do i do that?
Example:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

mylist.Add(Thomas);

mylist.Add(Bob);

mylist.Add(Andy);

this.scenariocontext.Add("myList", myList);
```

//created a new list to retrieve the data in a different step scenario

```
List<string> NewList = new List<string>();

NewList  = this.ScenarioContext.Get<string>("myList");
```

When I try to retrive the values from the dictionary I get this error
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: what is type of `ScenarioContext`?

Comment: https://specflow.org/documentation/Sharing-Data-between-Bindings/

Comment: ScenarioContext.Add(stringKey, List<string>);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the `scenarioContext` is declared as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, you can retrieve the value, which is a list in this case, by key. This is how your code would look like:

**Option 1**

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> scenarioContext = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<string> myList = new List<string>();

myList.Add("Thomas");

myList.Add("Bob");

myList.Add("Andy");

scenarioContext.Add("myList", myList);

List<string> newList = new List<string>();

newList = scenarioContext["myList"];
```

Update: I just found out that ScenarioContext in SpecFlow has an additional Getter. You are casting the List as string in your last line of code, it should look like this:

```
NewList  = this.ScenarioContext.Get<List<string>>("myList");
```

Comment: When I try to retrieve it, i get this error: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'."

Comment: did you use newList = scenarioContext["myList"]; ?

Comment: The error that you got means that you are using `string` in place of `List<string>`.

Comment: I'm using a list List<string> NewList = new List<string>();

NewList  = this.ScenarioContext.Get<string>("myList");

Comment: I see, SpecFlow has its own implementation of Getter. So, you need to change it to  `NewList = this.ScenarioContext.Get<List<string>>("myList")`;

Answer (score 0):

You can read dictionary using key .In your case  it must look like:
newList = this.ScenarioContext["myList"];